# How to get my posts from Hygraph to show them on my React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, content-management-system, graphcms, hygraph

I want to connect my react app with hygraph, to show my posts on the page. I have problem with writing http request, I got such example from chatgpt:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const apiUrl = 'myApiUrl';
  const apiToken = 'myApiToken';

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${apiToken}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            query: `
              query Komunikaty {
                komunikaty {
                  date
                  id
                  publishedAt
                  title
                }
              }
            `,
          }),
        });

        const result = await response.json();
        setData(result.data.komunikaty);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Your CMS Data</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <strong>{item.title}</strong> - {item.publishedAt}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

But the response is [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpGD3.png)

What should I do to get my posts?

Thank you

I have been trying to do this with axios but didn't get any results, also I have tryiedto do this with Apollo and I also didn't get the result

Comment: The response looks like it's not throwing an error, so the actual query is being sent and some sort of data is coming back.

What's the body of the response?

Also, when you use your query in Hygraph's API Explorer (it's a Graphiql variation), do you get data back?

Comment: response body: https://ibb.co/RD69fp8  and there is Hygraph API Playground screenshot https://ibb.co/9qF16WB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I did `console.log(result)` and I saw 403 error "Not allowed", so I created new permission for all models and I have deleted HTTP request header `` Authorization: `Bearer ${apiToken}`, ``. Now it works.